# Getting Me using Azure OAuth 2 Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to use Azure OAuth2 to authenticate a user, then get some information about them. Here is what I am doing now.

1. If code is not in URI, redirect them to: https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID_HERE/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
2. This redirects them back the the URL, but passes the code in the URI
3. The page takes the code from the URI and makes a POST request to: https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID_HERE/oauth2/v2.0/token with body of: 

   `"grant_type" = "authorization_code"
   "code" = "INSERT THE CODE"
   "client_id", "INSERT THE CLIENT_ID"
   "client_secret", "INSERT THE CLIENT SECRET"`
4. This returns a valid access token
5. When I attempt to request user information via: https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6 with the access token in the Authorization header, I get an error message stating the token has expired.

I have tried multiple different endpoints, but none seem to work correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is some of the token information.

`aud: "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
scp: "openid profile email"`

Comment: Can you check the access token at e.g. https://jwt.ms? Especially check what scopes it contains and what is the audience (aud).

Comment: @juunas I just updated the the post with the aud and scp.

Comment: Hmm, you might need to request the `User.Read` scope.

Comment: Those scopes `openid profile email` only affect what goes in the Id token sent to your app I think.

Comment: Check the token again, might be that it's for Microsoft Graph API, in which case you call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Comment: @juunas You are a Genius. Thanks mate.

If you post the answer below, I will give you credit.

Comment: Well luckily the solution was simple this time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the `User.Read` scope, and then call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` instead of the Azure AD Graph API endpoint.
That said, you might also be able to ask for `https://graph.windows.net/User.Read` as a scope and call AAD Graph, but that API is being deprecated so I'd rather use the current API :)

The scopes you have (`openid profile email`) only affect what goes in the Id token that your app gets AFAIK and do not affect your ability to call APIs.

Comment: The way i did it was to add the scope to application, to its easier that way.